# The font, "riffic free-bold" doesn't work in p5.js

Tags: javascript, fonts, p5.js

So I'm doing the obvious...

```
var font;
function preload() {
    font = loadFont('assets/text/riffic.ttf');
}
function setup() {
    createCanvas(600, 600);
}
```

and then to call it I use...

```
function draw() {
    textFont(font);
    text("Hello", 100, 100);
}
```

When I try to use this font, the console tells me this...

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
at Substitution.getDefaultScriptName (p5.js:31993)
at Font.stringToGlyphs (p5.js:27954)
at Font.forEachGlyph (p5.js:28069)
at Font.getAdvanceWidth (p5.js:28144)
at p5.Font._textWidth (p5.js:63498)
at p5.Font._handleAlignment (p5.js:63523)
at p5.Font._getPath (p5.js:63339)
at p5.Font._renderPath (p5.js:63458)
at p5.Renderer2D._renderText (p5.js:48828)
at p5.Renderer2D.text (p5.js:48788)
```

but no matter where I get it from the font style "Riffic free-bold just will not work with p5.js for me! Is there some kind of reason for this? Is riffic free-bold different from other fonts? If so, how? (I REQUIRE riffic free-bold, so I can't just use another font.)

Comment: so  you're saying that if you replace `riffic.ttf` with some other font that resides in the same location, everything "works" as it should?

Comment: have you tried using the optional `callback` *and* `onError` arguments to `loadFont` to debug the issue? is there anything in the *browser* **developer** tools console indicating an error?

Comment: What I'm saying is this specific font style, no matter what I name it, will not work. the console thinks it's an issue with the p5.js code... Also sorry, I'll update my post to show where im using the font.

Comment: please also show any **error** messages you see in the console regarding this font - it may well be there's a problem with the file

Comment: is the font the same as [this one](https://fonts2u.com/riffic-bold.font) ... note the file there is `riffic.otf` not `riffic.ttf` - perhaps try that instead

Comment: No, I am definitely using a .ttf file, but I'll try that one to see if it works because it's the same font. Also I don't think it's an issue with the file because I tried to get it from MANY different places, all of them show the same error.

Comment: Good news! the .otf file that Jaromanda produced works perfectly! Bad news, we still don't know why it won't work with .ttf?

Comment: perhaps the riffic.ttf file is in some way "broken" (or not as p5.js expects a ttf to be) - have you tried different .ttf fonts (not riffic) to determine if p5.js is broken with ttf's perhaps?

Comment: Yeah, I actually have another .ttf font running on the same site, and it works perfectly, but I seriously doubt that the file is broken because I tried the same font from many different websites.

Comment: ahh, but if `riffic.ttf` is indeed incompatible with p5.js (that's why I said "broken" in quotes), then it wouldn't matter where you got it from :p

Comment: without your post saying where you got riffic.ttf, there is literally no way for anyone to say why it might not work, because there's no [mcve] to run through =) (the only .ttf version I can find is almost twice the size of the [official .otf](https://www.fontspring.com/fonts/inky-type/riffic/riffic-bold), so entirely untrustworthy)